# How to find the maximum of a group with multiple maximas in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, max

**The table must be grouped by department and the maximum amount of the department must be returned**

Table A:

| Id | Name | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Abraham | HR |
| 2 | Michael Clarke | HR |
| 3 | Roy Thomas | Manager |
| 4 | Tom Jose | HR |
| 4 | Jerry Pinto | Manager |

Table B:

| M_Id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 5000 |
| 3 | 2500 |
| 4 | 1000 |
| 4 | 1500 |

**Expected Answer**

| Id | Name | Department | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Abraham | HR | 5000 |
| 2 | Michael Clarke | HR | 5000 |
| 3 | Roy Thomas | Manager | 2500 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select main.*

FROM

-- get all information from t1 and amount from t2
(
  select t1.*, t2.amount from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = m_id
) main

INNER JOIN

-- get max amount by department
(
  select department, max(amount) max_amount from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = m_id
  group by department
) summary

-- match with main by department and the max amount
on main.department = summary.department
and main.amount = summary.max_amount;
```

Result

```
+------+----------------+------------+--------+
| id   | name           | department | amount |
+------+----------------+------------+--------+
|    1 | John Abraham   | HR         |   5000 |
|    2 | Michael Clarke | HR         |   5000 |
|    3 | Roy Thomas     | Manager    |   2500 |
+------+----------------+------------+--------+
```

Example is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a4cdd94b415df204b0fd967263ba9dc8

Explanation

Since you want to get max amount by department, we created a subquery for that. We gave it an alias `summary`. That gave us this:

```
select department, max(amount)
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = m_id group by department;
+------------+-------------+
| department | max(amount) |
+------------+-------------+
| HR         |        5000 |
| Manager    |        2500 |
+------------+-------------+
```

We combined data that you wanted to report on by combining t1 and t2 tables and gave it an alias `main`. That gave us this:

```
select t1.*, t2.amount from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = m_id;
+------+----------------+------------+--------+
| id   | name           | department | amount |
+------+----------------+------------+--------+
|    1 | John Abraham   | HR         |   5000 | <-- want this
|    2 | Michael Clarke | HR         |   5000 | <-- want this
|    3 | Roy Thomas     | Manager    |   2500 | <-- want this
|    4 | Jerry Pinto    | Manager    |   1000 |
|    4 | Tom Jose       | HR         |   1000 |
+------+----------------+------------+--------+
```

We, then, ensured that both subqueries were joined based on the department and the amounts in both subqueries.